# Как подменить часть кода в странице в реальном времени?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Нужно подменить на одной странице код. Вроде того, как можно сделать отладчиком через Chrome, но только так, чтобы это работало всегда (в том числе при обновлении).
Как это сделать?

Comment: Можно, например, поменять исходники на стороне сервера, можно вклиниться в траффик и поменять его немного. Можно, в конце концов, написать расширение для браузера (не ясно какого только). Нужно больше подробностей, короче.

Comment: В трафик вклиниваться наверняка долго, хочется более простое решение. Расширение было бы не плохо использовать какое-то, браузер Chrome.

Comment: В вопрос вносите дополнения. Только "как написать расширение для того-то и того-то" - тоже плохой вопрос.

Comment: Может есть готовое решение. Да и если писать самому - хром может ругаться что расширение не с офф. магазина. Может уже есть готовое решение.

Comment: Вопрос "подскажите софт для ..." - тоже плохой вопрос на этом сайте. Тут не гугл.

Comment: Ничего страшного, может кто и подскажет.

Comment: Ну тогда смело можете переформулировать вопрос. Учитывая, что вам сказали что в новой формулировке он будет плохим - его очень быстро снесут.

Comment: Ну снесут и снесут, мне плевать. Ответ уже дали, мне подошло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C помощью https://tampermonkey.net/ для Chrome, в данном расширении можно написать javascript код который будет загружаться и исполняться на нужном web сайте при загрузке сайта.

Comment: Спасибо, это подойдет.